# image retrieved from baasbox javascript , not displaying in html page

Tags: jquery, html, base64, baasbox

I am using baasbox javascript sdk to retrieve images from baasbox server and display it on webpage.

I have retrieved the image file (base64 binary data)from Baasbox sever using fetchfile() 
but when I try to display it using

```
`BaasBox.fetchFile(item.FileID)
                        .done(function(resI) 

                            console.log("res ", resI);
                            uri = 'data:' + resD.data.contentType + ';charset=utf-8;base64,' + resI;
                            $('#listimages').append('<p><img src="' + uri + '" alt=""></img></p>');
                        })`
```

Image is not displayed. 
can anyone help me with example, how to display the retrieved image on html page? 
I am not sure if the problem is with browser, or base64 decoding

Answer (score 0):

This issue of the BaasBox Javascript SDK has been fixed some days ago.

Please see https://github.com/baasbox/JS-SDK/issues/27

The new SDK version should work as expected.